# How to get more than 20 Signers with ethers.js / hardhat / waffles

Tags: ethers.js, testing, hardhat, waffle

I'm using Hardhat with the waffle plugin to test my smart contract.

To get Signers (ether.js) I'm using :

```
await ethers.getSigners();
```

This return an array with 20 signers.
If I call again, I get the same 20 signers, but how do I get a new one ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `ethers.Wallet.createRandom()` from François Guyot this is how I managed to get many Signers for my tests.

ctx is your contract instance and addr1 is one of the Signer you got by calling  await ethers.getSigners();

```
            for( let i=0; i < nb; i++){
                // Get a new wallet
                wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
                // add the provider from Hardhat
                wallet =  wallet.connect(ethers.provider);
                // send ETH to the new wallet so it can perform a tx
                await addr1.sendTransaction({to: wallet.address, value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1")});
                
                await ctx.connect(wallet).CallYouContract())
            }
```

Answer (score 7):

You could generate a bunch of random signers by doing this:

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers'

export const randomSigners = (amount: number): Signer[] => {
  const signers: Signer[] = []
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    signers.push(ethers.Wallet.createRandom())
  }
  return signers
}
```

Comment: Thank you François for your help. To make it work with Hardhat and Waffle I had to add a provider but this helped me to go in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're using hardhat**, the default number of account (20) can be changed in the config:

hardhat.config.ts

```
networks: {
        hardhat: {
            accounts: {
                count: 60,
                // accountsBalance: 10000000000000000000000, // default value is 10000ETH in wei
            },
        },
    },
```

The `getSigners` function will retrieve all the accounts.

More parameters for the accounts are defined in the [hardhat documentation](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#accounts)